# Can I treat my ordinal data as categorical, and use those results to corellate with a 5 point likert scale?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, categorical-data, ordinal-data, likert

I have recently been reading about business ethics and have undertaken a research project concerning interest in ethical consumption. I am rusty on my stats so I am desperate to get to the bottom of this somehow.

I have found the Attitudes Towards Business Ethics Questionnaire (ATBEQ) from several journals online, and it consists of 30 questions which identify 6 ethical ideologies. 6 questions for each ideology on a 5 point likert scale from strongly disagree to strongly agree.

I was thinking maybe for my own research it could be possible to do 3 questions from only 4 ethical ideologies, and add up the points from the scales to see which ethical ideology every individual belongs to. My issue here is that because I have not been so in touch with my statistics, I dont know if I could treat ordinal likert scale data as categorical. Also I dont know if I could treat this as an independent variable as well too.

My aim was to see if I could measure this against ethical consumption from another 5 point likert scale survey I found to see how corellate most with ethical consumption. Could this at all be possible?

Comment: Is your question just can I treat likert data as ordinal?